# Swift Framework <-> ObjC interoperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, swift

I've got a dylib framework with some UIView subclasses made in swift which I've done to use the new `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` stuff.

So lets say I've got a `UITextField` subclass in there named `MyTextField.swift` like this:

**MyTextField.swift**

```
@IBDesignable class MyTextField: UITextField {

    // some properties etc.
    // content is irrelevant   
}
```

Now it compiles and works well in InterfaceBuilder so far so good. But what I need to do is import this special subclass into my Objective C implementation of the controller to set a property in code at runtime.

The framework (named `myViews`) has a header called `myViews.h` which I am able to import into the controllers header like this:

**MyViewController.h:**

```
@import myViews;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "myViews.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyTextField *txtName; // <-- This is the problem!

@end
```

This is where I'm stuck! So the class `MyTextField` is unknown from the imported headers. The `myViews.h` was automatically generated. I've tried to import the bridging-headers in there without success.

**myViews.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for myViews.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double myViewsVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for myViews.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char myViewsVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework
// using statements like #import <myViews/PublicHeader.h>

#import <myViews/MyTextField-Swift.h> // <-- This is what I've tried to import here which doesn't work as well.
```

Hope anybody may help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got droid :)  Would you happen to know how to export that swift class?

Comment: @AlexanderN Yes, I do!

Answer (score 0):

In your objective-c class, try importing your swift module like this:

`#import "<ModuleName>-Swift.h"`

Where ModuleName is the name of the module containing the swift code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already tried this but Xcode says `'MyTextField-Swift.h' file not found`. In general I think I need to just import the Framework and in the framework header I need to import the swift bridging headers. But I had no success yet.

Comment: I got an error, when importing with ```#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"``` as well. But ```#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>``` works. But beware, the first part is the *product name*, while the first part of the header-filename is the *module name*. They might be different.